# is there a way to force newly created linux/unix file permission to 775?

Tags: permissions

My linux system default file permission is 666 with a umask of 0. It is 664 with a umask of 0002 and it is 644 with a umask of 022. How do i force newly created file to have a 775 permissions? Also how do I change the linux default file permission of linux box from 666 to something else like a 755? I am running a debian based system.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want this?  This would result a huge possibility for security problems.  Making files executable by default is going to be very dangerous.

Comment: I understand the ramification of such setting but i would like to know if it is possible to change it. If  it is not allowed i can undestand why. Now the question is : is there a way to change it yes or no? Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

`umask` doesn't turn on bits, it only turns them off.  If the application you use to create the file or directory doesn't try to create with the executable bit set (for instance, `gcc` or `mkdir`), nothing you do with `umask` will add an executable bit.